# VBA Excel File Open Prompt Cancel Error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, file-processing

So I am using a file open prompt to gather a filename.
I then open this file in a background instance, parse information to a dictionary and close the file.
This works fine. 
The code for this is:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
sFullName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
```

If the user presses cancel, which is obviously a feasible scenario, I get the following error:

```
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

I have tried to change the 'gather' line to:

```
If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1) Then sFullName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
```

However this still brings up the error.  Even disabling alerts brings up an error or '400'.
Any help on how to make this popup or handle it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GetSaveAsFilename`i.e.

```
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
If strFileName = "False" Then MsgBox "User cancelled"
```

Comment: Great, worked.  Added some code further on down also to help and it did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

You need check the bounds to determine if anything was selected

```
with Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    .Show

    if (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then
        '// dialog dismissed with no selection
    else
        sFullName = .SelectedItems(1)
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
I'm pretty new to vba excel so all help in formatting is appreciated.
At the moment I only am really using the with block for my workbook_open() for some reason.  I should really start to implement it more if I do more projects in the future